# Examples of Incomplete Spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

A metric space is complete if every cauchy sequence is convergent.
To make space incomplete either i can change the metric or the ambient space.
For example if I change real numbers into rational number with usual metric ( absolute value ) it would be incomplete. On the other hand if have a some kind of metric on some space it would be incomplete though.

**My question is:** Can someone give examples of incomplete spaces such that either they have unusual metric or unusual ambient space other than rational numbers etc ?

Comment: Take any complete metric space and remove one (or two) points?

Comment: Actually, any space with the discrete metric is complete: every Cauchy sequence is constant.

Comment: Quang Hoang, it would be trivial.

Comment: @TöreDenizBoybeyi the definition of trivial is, in this case, rather personal.

Comment: Then, are there any examples without removing points ?

Comment: There is a theorem which says that any metric space can be be embedded densely and isometrically in a complete metric space. So in a sense, removing points from a complete metric space is the only way to produce one which is incomplete. Of course, that assumes that you know what all the complete metric spaces are...

Comment: Can anyone say which theorem is it ?

Comment: Look up "completion of metric spaces" in any topology textbook or on the web.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an example of a metric $d$ on $\mathbf R$ such that  $(\mathbf R,d)$ is *not* complete.

Set $d(x,y)=\bigl\lvert\mathrm e^{-x}-\mathrm e^{-y}\bigr\rvert$. It trivially satisfies the axioms of a metric.

Now the sequence of natural numbers is a Cauchy sequence. Indeed choose $\varepsilon> 0$ and let $N$ be an integer such that  $\;\mathrm e^{-N}<\dfrac\varepsilon2$. If $p,q>N$, we have:
$$d(p,q)=\bigl\lvert\mathrm e^{-p}-\mathrm e^{-q}\bigr\rvert\le\mathrm e^{-p}+\mathrm e^{-q}<2\cdot\mathrm e^{-N}<\varepsilon. $$

This sequence does not converge. If it did converge to some $u\in \mathbf R$, we would have $\;d(n,u)=\bigl\lvert\mathrm e^{-n}-\mathrm e^{-u}\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$ if $n>N_1$ for some $N_1$. If $n>\max(N,N_1)$, this implies
$$\mathrm e^{-u}<\mathrm e^{-n}+\varepsilon<\frac{3\varepsilon}2.$$
As $\varepsilon$ was chosen arbitrarily, this means $\mathrm e^{-u}=0$, which cannot be.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$m_0 := \{t \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} : \{t_1, t_2, \ldots \} \text{ is finite} \}$$
be the sequences of real numbers that only take on finitely many values.
Equip it with the sup-norm, i.e. $$\| t \|_\infty := \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |t_i|.$$
This is an incomplete normed vector space (so it's also a metric space). To see this, consider the sequences $$t^{(1)} = (1, 0, 0, \ldots),$$ $$t^{(2)} = (1, \frac{1}{2}, 0, 0, \ldots ),$$ $$t^{(3)} = (1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, 0, 0, \ldots )$$
and so on.
Assume $i > j$, then we have
$$\|t^{(i)} - t^{(j)} \|_\infty = \| (0, \ldots, 0, \frac{1}{j+1}, \ldots, \frac{1}{i}, 0, 0, \ldots ) \|_\infty = \frac{1}{j+1},$$
this converges to $0$ for $i,j \rightarrow \infty.$ Therefore $(t^{(i)})_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a cauchy sequence in $m_0$. But it's limit (in the bigger space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ of sequences of real numbers) is
$$(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \ldots, \frac{1}{i}, \ldots ),$$
which is not an element of $m_0$. Hence, $m_0$ cannot be complete.