# non complete metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

I'm looking for a riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not complete.

In this forum post [second one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419839/examples-of-incomplete-spaces) someone gave an example of a metric $d$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $(\mathbb R,d)$ is not complete. I tried to generalize this result on $\mathbb R^2$ and find the riemannian metric $g$ of $d$, but it didn't work.

Does someone have another idea how to find one or how to use the result in the forum post to construct one.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for a metric that's compatible with the standard topology on $\mathbb R$? (Otherwise, just bijectively map $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ and use the metric $d$ on $\mathbb R$ that you already have.)

Comment: I should have wrote it more carfully. The exersice says: Find a riemannian metric on $\mathbb R^2$ which is not complete. So one must distinguish between riemannian metric $g$ and the metric $d$, also called riemannian distance.  The connection between $g$ and $d$ is given by $d(p,q)=inf{L[c]|c:[a,b]→M, c piece wise smooth,c(a)=p,c(b)=q}$ where $L[c]=\int_a^b (g(\dot{c},\dot{c}) )^{1/2}dt$. So i thought i can use the example that i postet to somehow construct the riemannian metric $g$ out of the given $d$.

Answer (score 4):

Map $\mathbb R^2$ to the sphere minus a point, using [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection), and use the metric induced by the standard metric on the sphere. Then sequences that go off to infinity (in any direction) are Cauchy sequences, since on the sphere they converge to the projection point; but there's no corresponding point in $\mathbb R^2$ for them to converge to.

Answer (score 1):

$f:(\{ x| |x|<1\},\|\ \|_2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $ f(x)=\frac{x}{1-|x|}$. Here $f$ gives a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.